# stripos function in php not returning correct result

Tags: php, function, case-sensitive

In php, `stripos()` performs case sensitive searching of a character and returns its position. But in the following code, position of the character `L` is returned irrespective of its case sensitivity.

```
<?php

$a = array('hello','world');
foreach($a as $val) {

echo $val;

echo stripos($val, 'L'); //returns hello2world3
}
?>
```

Comment: strpos is case sensitive. stripos is case INsensitive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From php documentation

- [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) is for case-insensitive search.
- If you want case sensitive search then you should use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).